# ¿Cómo hacer que el estado de una variable sea el mismo que en la instancia anterior de el programa y pueda seguirse modificando en C++?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa de gestor de empleados en **`C++`**. El programa guarda los datos que el usuario le introduce sobre cada empleado en un archivo `.txt.` Hasta ahí todo funciona bien pero quiero que los `ID` se los asigne automáticamente **`iniciando en 100000`** para el primer empleado registrado y que los vaya **`aumentando de 1 en 1`**. Hasta ahora el programa lo hace a medias pues cuando se cierra y se vuelve a abrir la variable `ID` vuelve a su estado original.

Comment: Debes hacer persistente ese dato. Guardando en otro archivo.  O en el mismo

Answer (score 4):

La característica que necesitas recibe el nombre de [Persistencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistencia_(inform%C3%A1tica)) y hay varias maneras de garantizar la persistencia de datos:

- **Memoria**: Es posible persistir en [memoria no volátil](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoria_no_vol%C3%A1til), es una opción muy común en [sistemas embebidos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_embebido) sin [sistema de archivos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_archivos).
- **Archivo**: Persistir guardando los datos en un [archivo local](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_archivos) es de las opciones más fáciles y comunes, muy utilizada en [aplicaciones de escritorio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplicaci%C3%B3n_de_escritorio).
- **Registro del sistema**: En los sistemas Windows es posible almacenar datos en el [registro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_de_Windows).
- **Base de datos**: En ocasiones, las aplicaciones persisten información en [bases de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_de_datos), siendo más común en aplicaciones [cliente-servidor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliente-servidor).
- **Servidor**: También es posible persistir datos en un servidor remoto, suele ser la solución adoptada por los [terminales tontos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_tonta), o terminales que actúen como tales.
- **Nube**: En la Internet moderna, es posible persistir datos remotamente en la nube, se trata de una solución habitual en [dispositivos móviles](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispositivo_m%C3%B3vil).

¿Qué persistencia necesitas?

---

Entiendo por tu pregunta que la persistencia es en archivo (aunque podrías contemplar las otras mencionadas) y por la descripción de tu problema tienes dos opciones:

- Al arrancar la aplicación, cargar todos los empleados, contar cuántos hay y asignar a la variable `ID` el recuento de empleados sumándole `100000` o...
- ... guardar un archivo con el valor del último `ID` asignado y actualizar dicho archivo cada vez que se asigne un nuevo `ID`.

Comment: Claro y conciso.

Answer (score 1):

La única manera de solucionar el problema es, como te han comentado vía comentarios, almacenar el valor de la variable en un fichero.

Un posible algoritmo podría ser así:

- Al arrancar la aplicación se comprueba si existe el fichero. Si existe se carga dicho valor en la variable... si no se deja su valor por defecto.
- Cada vez que se da de alta un empleado nuevo se incrementa el valor de la variable (esto se supone que ya lo tienes)
- Al finalizar el programa se guarda el valor actual de la variable en el fichero.

El fichero puede ser el mismo que el que contiene la lista de empleados u otro diferente. Salvo especificación explícita es algo que, así de primeras, dependerá de cómo estructures la información.